# How $X$ noise propagates through controlled-$S$ gate

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-circuit, transpile, compiling

I am struggling to find how an $X$ noise propagates through a controlled-$S$ gate.

[Here`s the circuit.](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%5D%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quirk, the trick to finding the equivalent operation after an intermediate operation is to check that their phase kickback exactly cancels even when operating on entangled qubits:

[image]

Note that the bottom qubit ends up OFF. This is a proof that X before CS is the inverse of $S \cdot X \cdot CZ$ after CS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to find how an $X$ error before a $cS$ (controlled-S, where $S=diag(1,i)$) gate behave after a $cS$ gate.

What you should solve is simply the equation (I assume an $X$ error on the control as in your circuit):

$$cS X_1 = E cS \Leftrightarrow E=cS X_1 cS^{\dagger}$$

Solving it on mathematica gives the following two-qubit matrix for $E$ (in the two-qubit computational basis):

[image]

In practice if you decompose $E$ on the Pauli-matrices you will have a non-trivial expression (linear combination of tensor products of $I$, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ operators) as $cS$ is non-Clifford. Finally, given the shape of the $E$ matrix above, I think in that case the error propagates on the two registers after the gate.

Comment: May you share the code on wolframalpha.com?

Comment: I am not sure of how I could give it to you through wolfram alpha website. However, you can contact me on linkedin and I can provide you the code.

Comment: Thanks!! I sent you a request.